# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Vmax'

Tags: pandas

**I try to solve this problem:**

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Vmax'`

**This is a code:**

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))

plt.plot(data.indice_tiempo, data.Vmax, label = 'Precio máximo')
plt.plot(data.indice_tiempo, data.Vmin, label = 'Precio mínimo')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.ylabel('Precio')
#plt.ylim(-10,40)
plt.show()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e6aa3f72c6f3> in <module>
      1 plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))
      2 
----> 3 plt.plot(data.indice_tiempo, data.Vmax, label = 'Precio máximo')
      4 #plt.plot(data.indice_tiempo, data.Vmin, label = 'Precio mínimo')
      5 plt.legend()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Vmax'
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(data.columns)`?

Comment: Index(['sector_id', 'sector_nombre', 'variable_id',
       'actividad_producto_nombre', 'indicador', 'unidad_de_medida', 'fuente',
       'frecuencia_nombre', 'cobertura_nombre', 'alcance_tipo', 'alcance_id',
       'alcance_nombre', 'indice_tiempo', 'valor'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: The column `Vmax` is missing. So you can't use `data.Vmax` or `data['Vmax']`

Answer (score 0):

I maybe need more info to help you but I guess you are trying to plot a line representing the price of something and point the max and min price.

You can try something like this:

```py
#Create dummy data
data_dict = {"indice_tiempo":[24,25,21,31,32,21],
         "fecha":["01/06","02/06","03/06","04/06","05/06","06/06"]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

#Set column "fecha" as index
data = data.set_index("fecha")

#Create plot
plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))
max_data = data.indice_tiempo.sort_values(ascending=False).head(1) #Filter max price data
min_data = data.indice_tiempo.sort_values(ascending=False).tail(1) #Filter min price data
plt.plot(data.index, data.indice_tiempo) #Plot line
plt.scatter(max_data.index, max_data.values, label = 'Precio máximo') #Plot max price point
plt.scatter(min_data.index, min_data.values, label = 'Precio mínimo') #Plot min price point
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Fecha')
plt.ylabel('Precio')
plt.show()
```

The error you are getting from Python is telling you that you don't have any column called "Vmax" in your dataframe.

I guess you're trying to call a function to get the max price.

For that you need to do this --> `df.column_name.max()` or `df["column_name"].max()`

[Resulting PLOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2FiM.png)